# MS Access Recordset Moving on Search even if no match found?

Tags: ms-access

This is driving me nuts. I have an access VBA form where I want to allow users to type a document number into a box in order to jump directly to that record.

The underlying table as a field "DocNum", and the number is always sequential. I want the searchbox to display the current Doc Number the user is on, if they type in a different number and hit enter, it should either jump to that record if it exists, or if it doesn't exist, stay on the current record.

I'm trying to accomplish thisby having a hidden textbox bound to "DocNum", and an unbound visible box on top of it. On Form_Current() the unbound box is made to match the underlying field. After, update I run the following code to perform the search.

```
Private Sub txt_DocNumSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs As Object
        
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    
    With rs
        rs.FindFirst "[DocNum] = " & Str(Me![txt_DocNumSearch])
        
        If rs.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record not found."
            GoTo Cleanup
        Else
            Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
   
Cleanup:
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
            Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

What's driving me insane is that even when it doesn't find a match.... it skips to the next record anyway. No matter what I do... move last, trying to bookmark before I even search, etc... I can't get it to not jump forward. What am I missing?

Comment: This is a kinda strange UI. Normally you put the search box outside the data section, e.g. search box is in form header, data is in Details section (single or continuous form). Then your code will simply work (you should still use Gustav's version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying it:

```vb
Private Sub txt_DocNumSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    
    With rs
        .FindFirst "[DocNum] = " & Str(Me![txt_DocNumSearch])        
        If .NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "Record not found."
        Else
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        End If
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried, but same issue.

Comment: Then your key type just causes a move to the next record, it is not the code. Set the property of the form to run through fields in one record only when pushing Enter.

Comment: Haha, was just coming to that conclusion myself, a separate database (where I did the same method) doesn't have this issue. What property is it that controls this? I don't remember setting it to anything unusual.

Comment: It is _Form, Properties, Other, third entry_.